# Garbage values assigned while using dynamic input; in C language

Tags: c

The problem is that,in the output the attributes sp,bp,temp,cold,fever and stomach are assigned with garbage values and also, the strings entered for symp[i] are not stored properly.
this is not the complete program, it still has some more additions to be done.

the program as follows.. header files are stdio.h and conio.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{    
 char * symp[10];
 int n=0,i,sp,dp,cold,fever,stomach;    
 float temp;   
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter your body temperature: ");    
 scanf("%f",&temp);    
 printf("Enter your systolic BP: ");    
 scanf("%d",&sp);    
 printf("Enter your diastolic BP: ");    
 scanf("%d",&dp);    
 printf("Enter the no of symptoms: ");    
 scanf("%d",&n);    
 printf("Enter the symptoms you have, one by one\n");
 fever=cold=stomach=0;    
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
 {    
  scanf("%s",symp[i]);    
  printf("i=%d\tn=%d\n",i,n);    
  if(symp[i]=="cough")    
  { cold=cold+1;}    
  if(symp[i]=="sneezing")    
  { cold=cold+1;}    
  if(symp[i]=="running_nose")    
  { cold=cold+1;}   
  if(symp[i]=="headache")    
  { cold=cold+1;fever=fever+1;}    
  if(symp[i]=="chill")    
  { fever=fever+1;  }  
  if(symp[i]=="weakness")    
  { fever=fever+1; }   
  if(symp[i]=="stomach_pain")
  { stomach=stomach+1; }   
  if(symp[i]=="diarrhoea")
  { stomach=stomach+1;}    
  if(symp[i]=="vomiting")    
  { stomach=stomach+1;fever=fever+1;}
  if(symp[i]=="throat_pain")   
  { cold=cold+1;}    
  if(symp[i]=="body_pain")
  { fever=fever+1;}
 }
printf("Your temperature is: %f\n",temp);
printf("Your BP is: %d/%d\n",sp,dp);
printf("The symptoms are:\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 printf("%s\n",symp[i]);
 }
printf("cold: %d\nfever: %d\nstomach: %d",cold,fever,stomach);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Please indent and remove the empty lines. No one likes scrolling.

Comment: You must check the `scanf()` return value, you can't complain about **garbage values** because your code is unsafe since it has no error checking.

Comment: Some of your `if` conditions are lacking braces `{}`.

Comment: @user694733 you have eagle eyes, how can you notice that in this mess?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `if(symp[i]=="cough")`?

Comment: Sorry about the indent, i'm new here. just signed up..!!

Comment: depending on the symptoms, the program must give out the disease causing it. by comparing, i can increment the disease values which can fetch it.
well, those lines aren't included yet

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare `char[]` to static strings with `==`, you have to use `strcmp` or `strncmp`, something like:

```
 if (strcmp(symp[i], "headache"))
```

you also have to pass an *address* to `scanf("%s", ...)`, something like:

```
scanf("%s", &symp[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are `scanf()`ing a strnig and passing a `char *` to `scanf()` without initializing it

```
scanf("%s", symp[i]);
```

this is wrong.

You need to allocate space for the strings to be stored properly, so you can try to do it like this

```
char symp[100][10];
```

and then your `scanf()` would look like this

```
scanf("%99s", symp[i]);
/*      ^ this prevents overflowing `symp[i]' */
```

Then, as the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103417/1983495) by @[PaulEvans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312406/paul-evans) mentions, you need to use [`strcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare strings.